# Beginner C: Why two variables are initialed differently

Tags: c, memory

I have the following code that could not run successfully. the src is assigned a memory address but dest does not. I am using Xcode 5 for command line development

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char* src;
    char* dest;

    memcpy(src,  "This is source", 15);
    memcpy(dest, "This is destination", 20);

    strcat(dest, src);

    printf("Final destination string : |%s|", dest);

    return(0);
}
```

after declaration, src's value is "" and has an address, but dest is NULL. I know it is a stupid question but need some help to make this out.

**UPDATE**
After a bunch of investigation I started to know I need to initialize the space for the pointer before memcpy, though Xcode didn't provide me useful warning or exception that I can find easily.

The correct usage is to use malloc to initialize the space then do the memcpy.

```
char* src;
char* dest;
src = malloc(sizeof(char)*15);
dest = malloc(sizeof(char)*34);

memcpy(src,  "This is source", 15);
memcpy(dest, "This is destination", 20);
```

Or we can also use array of char and leave enough space on dest.

```
char src[15];
char dest[34];

memcpy(src,  "This is source", 15);
memcpy(dest, "This is destination", 20);
```

Comment: *Both* `src` and `dst` contain garbage values in your example. They are *not* initialized. Whatever they happen to hold initially is pure accident. It is your responsibility to initialize your variables. No one will do it for you.

Comment: I know right now this question get some negative points so I could not raise more questions on SF. I would thank you if you see my update please add the points back. for a beginner you cannot assume this is the common sense, as if I should not have asked. But the warnings and errors in Linux and Mac could be different and something is not intuitive enough to realize this issue. On Xcode it gives you a value of 0 in the watcher when you are looking at an overflow array element which is hard to judge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behavior. You're using the values of automatic storage variables `src` and `dest` before initializing them.

You wrote

> "the src is assigned a memory address"

and this assumption is **wrong!** (big exclamation mark). The variable is uninitialized and anything may happen when you use it that way. Period, no discussion.

In a C program there are two kinds of variables:

- static storage, which means the storage the variable uses is determined at linkage time. Global variables and within a function variables with the `static` initializer are of that kind. Static scope variables are initialized to 0 at program load.
- automatic storage, which means the storage of the variable comes into existence when the program is *executed*.

In addition to that, C objects can also be of dynamic storage, which is allocated with `malloc` or its relatives.

What does this mean for you? *You must initialize those variables.* If you place them in static storage they get initialized to 0, which is a perfectly fine value for a pointer, but dereferencing it, which is what your code does, is not allowed. So you must initialize them to the address of a compatible object (=memory region), that matches the use of the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You initialized neither src nor dest so it is not clear where you are going to copy string literals.
The program has undefined behaviour.

You could do the same using arrays. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char src[] = "This is source";
    char dest[34] = "This is destination";


    strcat( dest, src );

    printf( "Final destination string : |%s|", dest );

    return 0;
}
```

Or another approach using pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *s1 = "This is source";
    const char *s2 = "This is destination";

    char *dest = malloc( strlen( s1 ) + strlen( s2 ) + 1 );

    strcat( strcpy( dest, s2 ), s1 );

    printf( "Final destination string : |%s|", dest );

    free( dest );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pointers, before you use `memcpy`, you must explicitly reserve or allocate space for storing the bytes you are copying over using `malloc` (or other memory allocation routines):

```
char *src = NULL;

/* add 1 byte for '\0' string terminator... */
src = malloc(strlen("This is source") + 1); 
if (!src) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not reserve memory for src pointer\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* copy over bytes (including terminator byte)... */
memcpy(src, "This is source", 15);

/* do stuff with 'src'... */

/* don't forget to free 'src' when you are done with it... */
free(src);
```

When using `strcat`, the destination pointer `dest` should also have been allocated sufficient space to store the concatenated, terminated result. The code snippet above should provide sufficient hints on how to do this.

Comment: but the first variable "src" is successfully assigned value "This is source" using the same code for dest. why "dest" is not working but "src" works

Comment: It doesn't matter if one variable "works". If you don't preallocate sufficient space for your pointers with `malloc` or similar memory allocation routines, the program is wrong and you will observe "weird" or inconsistent behavior, such as what you see.

Comment: Before going further, you should read up on pointers and memory allocation/deallocation. You are setting yourself up for a world of hurt if you don't go in managing pointer memory correctly.

Comment: @HanYi Zhang: Variable `src` was *not* "successfully assigned" anything. Variable `src` in your experiment contained a garbage value that just happened not to cause any crash by pure accident.

Comment: The example with `strlen()` inside `malloc()` argument doesn't make much sense, you almost never need the length only for malloc. In reality, you would have a `const char *` for the string, a `int` for the result of `strlen()` and then you would use it with both `malloc()` and `memcpy()`. Also the example is pretty much synthetic, as you would normally use `char buffer[50]` and `sizeof buffer` or in C99 even `int size = 50` and `char buffer[size]`.

Comment: Also you wouldn't normaly name a destination variable `src`.

Comment: Good points, but I'm trying to write an answer that corrects the asker's use of memory management, not change the program's logic or how variables are initially defined. HTH, Pavel.

Answer (score -2):

you need to use malloc or set your pointers to a memory of an existing array:
you need to do that because your pointers as they are right now point to random areas of your memory which you operate on a sure way to crashes or general system instability
i.e:

```
    src=malloc(80);
```

or

```
    char mem1[160];
    src=mem1;
    dst=mem1+80;
```

//or

```
    char mem2[89];
    dst=mem2;
```

Comment: This is not how character arrays are declared, use `char buffer[100]`, not `char[100] buffer`.

Comment: well you are right it's been over 20 years since i wrote in c,i will correct it. though the main point of my answer still stands: using arrays instead of malloc() can be easier to grasp for a beginner.